# Загрузка изображений в PixiJS

Tags: javascript, текстура, pixijs, спрайт

Хочу загрузить обычное png изображение в pixijs и сделать из него спрайт. Открыл пример на http://pixijs.io/examples/#/basics/basic.js. Внутри есть кода работающая функция PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(), отвечающая одновременно за загрузку и создание спрайта. Однако, я хочу создать спрайт из кэша заранее загруженных текстур. Пишу такой код:

```
PIXI.loader.add("zombie.png").load();
let bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resource["zombie.png"]);
```

После чего консоль браузера пишет, что не может обнаружить текстуру

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zombie.png' of undefined"
```

Если использовать сallback в функции load() текстура в нем обнаружится, спрайт создастся и все заработает.

Получается, что после вызова PIXI.loader.add().load() текстура могла еще непрогрузиться, и надо инициализировтаь ее в сallback'e или дождаться ее загрузки, или все же проблема в чем-то ином?

Comment: На будущее, проблема  по всей видимости связана с асинхронным вызовом функций. Нужно будет почитать о нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
PIXI.loader
    .add('spritesheet', '/js/sprites/hero.json')
    .load(onAssetsLoaded);
function onAssetsLoaded()
{
  
    var heroInactivity = [];
    var heroAnim = heroInactivity;
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var val = i < 16 ? '0' + i : i;
        heroInactivity.push(PIXI.Texture.fromFrame('hero' + val + '.png'));
    }
    var heroHello = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var val = i < 16 ? '0' + i : i;
        heroHello.push(PIXI.Texture.fromFrame('heroHello' + val + '.png'));
    }
    var heroStep =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var val = i < 16 ? '0' + i : i;
        heroStep.push(PIXI.Texture.fromFrame('heroStep' + val + '.png'));
    }
    var heroRun =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var val = i < 16 ? '0' + i : i;
        heroRun.push(PIXI.Texture.fromFrame('heroRun' + val + '.png'));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]